# get user input from serial or SD card then execute command in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm making an Arduino project that uses serial, so I need a simple command system, that I want it to accept commands and do them, or from a file on an SD card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any problems ? It is so easy, just use google.

```
String a;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}
void loop() {
    while(Serial.available()) {
    a= Serial.readString();// read the incoming data as string
    Serial.println(a);
}
```

Or the second example for catching characters

```
int incomingByte = 0;
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingByte = Serial.read(); // read the incoming byte:
    Serial.print(" I received:");
    Serial.println(incomingByte);
    }
}
```